# Order of attributes in disassembled code

Tags: c#, attributes, reflector, disassembly

When inspecting disassembled code that has been exported using [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) I have noticed that the order of [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on any given entity is not always maintained.

I've seen this when comparing the disassembled code of two versions of the same assembly (that has seen some minor code changes between the two versions), in classes that have not actually changed between the versions.

e.g.

```
[WebBrowsable, Personalizable]
public int SomeProperty ...
```

vs

```
[Personalizable, WebBrowsable]
public int SomeProperty ...
```

This is pretty inconvenient as it makes it look as if files that have not changed, have.

What controls the order of attributes in this scenario, and is there anything that can be done to maintain the order?

Comment: Yes, painful.  Bit of a bug in Reflector in my book.  No easy workaround either, send an email to Redgate.

Comment: @Hans: Agreed. I've emailed Redgate, will report back if I hear anything interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664616(v=vs.71).aspx)

> The order in which attributes are specified in such a list, and the order in which sections attached to the same program entity are arranged, is not significant. For instance, the attribute specifications [A][B], [B][A], [A, B], and [B, A] are equivalent.

That doesn't quite say that there is nothing that can be done to maintain the order, but it does say that the compiler doesn't have to pay attention to the ordering of the attributes and thus is free to reorder as it see fit. If you want to guarantee the ordering, you are probably going to have to modify the assembly post-build. There is probably a simpler way to solve your problem.

Comment: Could you update your post with a link to that part in the specification?

Comment: Jason was faster, but I have the link :P http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664616(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Richard Ev: It's §17.2 of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

The order of attributes does not affect the semantics of the code, and is simply an artefact of how the C# compiler compiles a project. it's probably chaotic emergant behaviour depending on what else is in your project. There's not much you can do about this, unfortunately...

Comment: Agreed that the attribute order doesn't impact the functionality of the code, it's just slowing down my diffing activities.